# Creating an array/slice to store DB Query results in Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm just getting started with golang and I'm attempting to read several rows from a Postgres `users` table and store the result as an array of `User` structs that model the row.

```
type User struct {
    Id  int
    Title string
}

func Find_users(db *sql.DB) {
    // Query the DB
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT u.id, u.title FROM users u;`)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    // Initialize array slice of all users. What size do I use here? 
    // I don't know the number of results beforehand
    var users = make([]User, ????)

    // Loop through each result record, creating a User struct for each row
    defer rows.Close()
    for i := 0; rows.Next(); i++ {
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &title)
        if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

        log.Println(id, title)
        users[i] = User{Id: id, Title: title}
    }

    // .... do stuff
}
```

As you can see, my problem is that I want to initialize an array or slice beforehand to store all the DB records, but I don't know ahead of time how many records there are going to be.

I was weighing a few different approaches, and wanted to find out which of the following was most used in the golang community -

1. Create a really large array beforehand (e.g. 10,000 elements). Seems wasteful
2. Count the rows explicitly beforehand. This could work, but I need to run 2 queries - one to count and one to get the results. If my query is complex (not shown here), that's duplicating that logic in 2 places. Alternatively I can run the same query twice, but first loop through it and count the rows. All this would work, but it just seems unclean.
3. I've seen examples of expanding slices. I don't quite understand slices well enough to see how it could be adapted here. Also if I'm constantly expanding a slice 10k times, it definitely seems wasteful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go has a built-in `append` function for exactly this purpose. It takes a slice and one or more elements and appends those elements to the slice, returning the new slice. Additionally, the zero value of a slice (`nil`) is a slice of length zero, so if you append to a nil slice, it will work. Thus, you can do:

```
type User struct {
    Id    int
    Title string
}

func Find_users(db *sql.DB) {
    // Query the DB
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT u.id, u.title FROM users u;`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var users []User
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &title)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Println(id, title)
        users = append(users, User{Id: id, Title: title})
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For my own education - That makes sense, but isn't it an inefficient operation? If my database has several thousand records it will expand/append to the slice several thousand times. I know modifying the slice itself is a quick operation since it's just a fixed reference to an underlying array, but it will still have to expand the underlying array several thousand times.

Comment: The standard algorithm to do this efficiently (which I assume `append` uses some variation of) is double the length of the underlying array every time you reallocate. This way, for *n* append operations, you perform only *log(n)* allocations, and you allocate approximately *2n* memory. Thus, the amount of space you allocate is linear in the number of append operations.

Comment: Ah yes, that does seem a lot more efficient. I marked your answer as accepted, much appreciated :)

Comment: @joshlf can you please elaborate further on that comment?

Comment: @Chris There's a pretty good explanation of the doubling algorithm - and why it's more efficient if you're appending many items - in this article: https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/dynamic-array-amortized-analysis

Answer (score 7):

User appending to a slice:

```
type DeviceInfo struct {
     DeviceName     string
     DeviceID       string
     DeviceUsername string
     Token          string
}

func QueryMultiple(db *sql.DB){
    var device DeviceInfo
    sqlStatement := `SELECT "deviceName", "deviceID", "deviceUsername", 
                 token FROM devices LIMIT 10`
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStatement)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var deviceSlice []DeviceInfo
    for rows.Next(){
        rows.Scan(&device.DeviceID, &device.DeviceUsername, &device.Token, 
                  &device.DeviceName)
         deviceSlice = append(deviceSlice, device)
    }
    fmt.Println(deviceSlice)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the capacity.

The following allocates an array that can hold 10,000 items:

```
users := make([]User, 0, 10_000)
```

but the array is, itself, still empty (`len(users) == 0`).

Now you can add up to at least 10,000 items before the array needs to be grown. For that purpose the `append()` works as expected:

```
users = append(users, User{...})
```

Maps are grown with a x2 of the size starting with 1. So it remains a power of two. I'm not sure whether slices are grown the same way (in powers of two). If so, then the allocated size above would be:

```
math.Pow(2, math.Ceil(math.Log(10_000)/math.Log(2)))
```

which is 2^14 which is 16,384.

---

**Note:** if your query uses a compatible `INDEX`, i.e. the `WHERE` clause matches the `INDEX` one to one, then an extra `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is *free* since the number of elements is known and it will return that number without the need to scan all the rows of your tables.